# Styling admin custom panel in Woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change this parameter in woocommerce panel. When I inspect this element it refer to a file `load-style.php` in `wp-admin`.

Do you know which CSS file allows to change this setting in admin panel of WC?

```css
.categorydiv div.tabs-panel, .customlinkdiv div.tabs-panel, .posttypediv div.tabs-panel, .taxonomydiv div.tabs-panel, .wp-tab-panel {
    min-height: 42px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 .9em;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your admin css like this, put this code to your functions.php ,and make your changes to your css. You may have to change your selectors.

```
 add_action('admin_head', 'custom_changes_css');

    function custom_changes_css() {
      echo '<style>
        .categorydiv div.tabs-panel, .customlinkdiv div.tabs-panel, .posttypediv div.tabs-panel, .taxonomydiv div.tabs-panel, .wp-tab-panel {
        min-height: 42px;
        max-height: 400px;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 0 .9em;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        background-color: #fdfdfd;
    }
      </style>';
    }
```